# Create array using foreach loop and pass it back with webworker postMessage

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have this web worker code:

```
onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20')
  .then( (res) => res.json() )
  .then( async (data) => {
    let imagesData = [];
    data.forEach( (item) => {
      fetch(item._links["wp:featuredmedia"][0].href)
      .then( (res) => res.json() )
      .then( (img) => {
        imagesData.push({
          title: item.title.rendered,
          link: item.link,
          src: img.source_url
        });
      });
    });
    await postMessage([imagesData]);
  });
} //end onmessage
```

I'm trying to create an array after that all the resources are fetched but I'm not able to achive this. at the moment the `imagesData` array will be empty and if moove it into the `.then()` where the array data are pushed, I will get multiple messages that will contain one single entry per array. How I can fix this to have a single array that will contain all the fetched information to pass back where the worker is created?

**NB: The code works fine in my main script, I'm just mooving it to a web worker! The problem isn't with the data provided from fetch and his structure but with the `imagesData` array that is the one I want to populate and send back to the main script.**

Comment: it's difficult to see if you don't give an url with some datas

Comment: Sorry but I can't provide the url. The problem isn't with the data but only how to pass them in an array after thay are fetched.

Comment: It might help to set breakpoints in your code via the inspector(sources) and check in each then() if there's actually data available and how it's structured in order to handle it correctly.

Comment: @Esger data are available, I'm using this code in a vue component that override the new chrome tab and works fine as expected, I want to implement a webworker to load faster the needed resources and the only problem I need to fix is how to create and pass a single array from worker to the main script! to be more clear, the array I want to fill and pass back is the `imagesData` one!

Comment: Are you using worker.onmessage() on the receiving side where you declared the worker?

Comment: @Esger I've fixed the problem. see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#forEach` executes synchronously, so by the time you get to `postMessage`, the array will still be empty.

Instead, what you need is [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

`Promise.all` turns an array of promises into a single promise that resolves to an array of their resolved values. The inner promises are executed in parallel, so the time to resolution should be roughly only as long as that of the longest-running inner promise.

Conveniently, passing an `async` function as the callback to `Array#map` transforms the original array into an array of promises. A common usage maps over an array of URL strings or parameters using `fetch` requests, wrapping the result in `Promise.all`:

```js
const usernames = await Promise.all(
    ['123', '456', '789'].map(async id => {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/users/${id}`)
        const { username } = await res.json()

        return username
    })
)
```

In your case, you need to replace this:

```js
let imagesData = [];
data.forEach( (item) => {
  fetch(item._links["wp:featuredmedia"][0].href)
    .then( (res) => res.json() )
    .then( (img) => {
      imagesData.push({
        title: item.title.rendered,
        link: item.link,
        src: img.source_url
      });
    });
  });
await postMessage([imagesData]);
```

With this:

```js
const imagesData = await Promise.all(
    data.map(async item => {
        const res = await fetch(item._links["wp:featuredmedia"][0].href)
        const img = await res.json()
        return {
            title: item.title.rendered,
            link: item.link,
            src: img.source_url
        }
    })
)
```

In addition, a worker's `postMessage` is synchronous, so there's no need to `await` it. You also don't need to wrap `imagesData` in an outer array before posting it:

```js
postMessage(imagesData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I will try it. Can you give some explainations about the code so this answer can help other peoples too?

Comment: @fed3vt I've edited the answer with some explanation.